# Passing data to Arduino from PHP via Python

Tags: python, php, arduino

I am trying to do Web API to control Arduino by using Python, but I have known web browser cannot open pyserial. Thus I am trying to send data to Arduino from PHP via Python by using serial communication. When I tried to use`shell_exec` and `sys.argv` on data sending from PHP to python, PHP can show the python print data. When I tried to use pyserial on data sending from python to Arduino, Arduino can receive the data from Python.

However, it doesn't work when I am trying to combine the both, the result is showed 'Undefined variable $output' on the php page that mean python cannot receive the data properly.

I have figured out the problem issue when I use `sys` and `serial` on Python at same time, I would like to know that is it sys.argv cannot work with serial communication? and can I have another way to connect the both side?

This is my entire php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Arduino Controlled based PHP</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="phppythontest.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden"  name="turn1" value="1" />
<input type="submit" name="turn1" value="1" />
</form>

<form action="phppythontest.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="turn2" value="2" />
<input type="submit" name="turn2" value="2" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["turn1"])) {
  $var1 = 2;
  $pyfilepath = "python_to_arduino_p2.py";
  $output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 $pyfilepath $var1");
}
if(isset($_POST["turn2"])) {
  $var1 = 3;
  $pyfilepath = "python_to_arduino_p2.py";
  $output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 $pyfilepath $var1");
}


echo $output;
 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my python code

```
import serial import time import sys

arduino = serial.Serial(port="/dev/cu.usbmodem1101",  baudrate=115200, timeout=.1)

def write_read(x):
    arduino.write(bytes(x,  'utf-8'))
    time.sleep(0.05)
    data = arduino.readline()
    return  data


while True:
    num = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    value  = write_read(num)
    print("total", num)
    break
```

I know I can send data to Arduino by using phpserial directly, but I want to trying this way and it is seem work.

I am trying to connect Arduino, PHP and Python for data transfer, I know it can be worked when I find the right code.

Comment: How's your code work? Your PHP is expecting a http POST response, where it is come from? If both `if()` doesn't receiving anything, you have a undefined $output.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in PHP, but to me it looks like the `output` variable isn't being defined. Since you only assign to that variable in your if statements, I would assume that the conditions in your if statements don't apply.

In addition, as far as I know the most common way to POST to the same page (which I assume you are trying to do here) is to just leave the action attribute empty (like `action=""`). If you're still on the same page after clicking either of the submit buttons (which is what you want) and it still doesn't work, you might try to log one or both of the post params (e.g. `echo $_POST["turn1"]`) or even the whole raw POST request data with `print_r($_POST)`. If you've gotten to this point and things still don't work, feel free to provide some of your findings / logs here so that we can try to assist further.

Comment: @halfer thanks for the tip, updated the answer :) I would've loved to comment but my reputation is still 9 points away from being able to comment everywhere. I feel like it's a weird system to not allow people to comment on questions when that's the intended way to ask clarifying questions, but it is what it is.

Comment: Yeah, it's a fair point. I should think the reason for that would be documented on [Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) somewhere...

Comment: I'm sure it's the best compromise for whatever problem they had to solve. Still, awkward for someone getting into answering question on SO. Anyway, thanks to the upvote I can now comment everywhere, so not my problem anymore ;)

Comment: Yep! Just bear in mind you will lose this permission if your score drops, so keep building it for a bit...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the another way to do it that use `fwrite`. Let PHP to write `.txt` file by Post request, and then Python read that `.txt` for avoiding `import sys` in Python script. I have made some change at PHP script and Python script as below:

I changed the PHP script from

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["turn1"])) {
  $var1 = 2;
  $pyfilepath = "python_to_arduino.py";
  $output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 $pyfilepath $var1");
}
if(isset($_POST["turn2"])) {
  $var1 = 3;
  $pyfilepath = "python_to_arduino.py";
  $output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 $pyfilepath $var1");
}


echo $output;
 
?>
```

to

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["turn1"])) {
  $var1 = 2;
  $myfile = "geeks_data.txt";
  $fh = fopen($myfile, "w");
  fwrite($fh, $var1);
  fclose($fh);

}
  if(isset($_POST["turn2"])) {
  $var1 = 3;
  $myfile = "geeks_data.txt";
  $fh = fopen($myfile, "w");
  fwrite($fh, $var1);
  fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

and Python script from

```
while True:
    num = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    value  = write_read(num)
    print("total", num)
    break
```

to

```
sleeptime = 10
speed = 0

while True:
    fo = open("geeks_data.txt", "r+")
    speed = fo.read()
    fo.close()
    print(speed)
    value = write_read(speed)
    print(value)
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

The result is working. Thanks.